# python regex fixed length fields witch specified characters and substrings

Tags: python, regex

How to capture a lines with fixed length fields including specified characters and a substrings? In this case:

- each fields contain 8 characters
- the first filed includes only 'RBE3' and whitespaces
- the third filed includes only '123'  and whitespaces

input:

```
123456781234567812345678123... (char numbers)
RBE3    323123       123121
  RBE3  323123   123    121
RBE3    32312300123     121
RBE3    3231231234      121
$ RBE3  323123123       121
R B E3  32312     123   121
     RBE32312       12313
```

output would be:

```
RBE3    323123       123121
  RBE3  323123   123    121
RBE3    32312300123     121
```

I tried with:

```
regex = r'^([RBE3\s]{8}.{8}[123\s]{8}.*\n)'
```

but it seems a completely wrong direction

Comment: https://regex101.com/ is super useful for figuring out the proper regex

Comment: If each field contains 8 characters, why are there 27 characters per line in each of your matches?

Comment: There are 27 chars because each line line can contain up to 9 fields and I did not write the rest.

Comment: The third line of your output doesn't satisfy your requirements...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly advise to not use a single regex for this. Better chop up your line into chunks of 8, then validate those.

If you insist, it's possible but ugly:

```
^(\s*RBE3\s*)(?<=^.{8})(.{8})(\s*123\s*)(?<=^.{24})(.*)$
```

***Explanation:***

```
^            # Start of string (or line, if you use multiline mode)
(\s*RBE3\s*) # Match RBE3, surrounded by any amount of whitespace --> group 1
(?<=^.{8})   # Make sure that we have matched 8 characters so far.
(.{8})       # Match any 8 characters --> group 2
(\s*123\s*)  # Match 123, surrounded by any amount of whitespace --> group 3
(?<=^.{24})  # Make sure that we have matched 24 characters so far.
(.*)         # Match the rest of the line/string --> group 4
$            # End of string/line
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/QLibEd/2). Note that only line 2 and 3 satisfy the requirements you stated.